# Firestore query returning empy when it shouldnt

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Android App that has a recyclerView, where it shows the data returning from a query.
However, the query returns null when it should return something.

This is the query:

```
db.collection("Usuarios").whereEqualTo("email", mUser.getEmail()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            //There can only be 1 document due to previus code.
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0);

            ArrayList<String> listasDelUsuario = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("idsListasDeCompra");
            //Query to get all "Listas de compra" docs where its field "id" is in the Array "listasDelUsuario" (I checked with Log and this array contains the id of all the user's listOfID
            db.collection("Listas de Compra").whereIn("id", listasDelUsuario).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                            //It enters in this if, so the query is returning no data
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a screenshot with both collections so u can check the values im checking are the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the query doesn't work, but in general I'd recommend accessing the list directly by its document ID, instead of querying for it:

```
db.collection("Listas de Compra").doc(listasDelUsuario).get()
```

Comment: Thanks, but what i try to do is to get all documents which ID is in that arraylist. I could iterate through the arraylist but i wanna save that data in a recyclerView that is already created, so if i do this i can save the arraylist that i get into the recyclerAdapter arraylist and use recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: And the problem was that the collection is called "Listas de compra" and i typed that c in uppercase

Comment: That's an easy one to overlook, so good that you spotted it 